# User cannot log in Mono/MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, monodevelop

While porting MVC3 application to Mono I'm receiving this error:

System.InvalidProgramException
Invalid IL code in System.Web.Security.MembershipProviderCollection:.ctor (): method body is empty.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.
Exception stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Security.Membership..cctor () [0x00010] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System.Web\System.Web.Security\Membership.cs:105
```

**MembershipProviderCollection**

```
public static MembershipProviderCollection Providers
    {
        get
        {
            return Membership.providers;
        }
    }
```

It works as expected under .Net but not the mono 3.0.1 compiler. How can I fix or work around this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by removing the reference to `System.Web`, adding a reference to `Mono's internal System.Web.ApplicationServices`, and then re-adding the `System.Web` reference. Not a clue in the world why this doesn't work without first removing System.Web, but it doesn't.